# Using read command on stdout

Tags: ios, bash

There is a command line utility's on iOS call sbutils
more specifically `sbalert` from that package.

It works like this

```
Sbalert -t "title" -d "text" -p
```

`-p` makes it ask for input but the way it shows the input once it goes through is `stdout`.

I cannot use the `read` command with it because I need what is entered in the prompt to be used in a command.

Comment: Why not just pipe stdout to your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
VAR=$(Sbalert -t "title" -d "text" -p)
echo $VAR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
password = your - password - here;
if ["$(sbalert -p -t "
    Admin Zone " -m "
    Please enter your password ")" == "$password"
];
then activator send libactivator.menu.bunch_of_letters;
fi
```

How would I mask the input

And sometimes password doesn't work and you need to try a few times, I don't mind that